# Add new Item to the listbox from other window

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, save, listboxitem

In my wpf application, I've created two view classes, DayView and CustomView. In DayView, there is a listbox consist of some entries. In listbox, there is stackpanel with 5 textboxes. In my CustomView class, also I've created stackpanel with 5 textboxes. when I enter data into those textboxes of CustomView and click on save button,the new entry should create and data should saved in respective textboxes of DayView.

CustomView class:

```
namespace TimeSheet
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for CustomView.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class CustomView : Window
{

    public List<Harvest_Project> projectList { get; set; }

    public List<Harvest_Client> clientList { get; set; }

    public Harvest_Project selectedProjectid { get; set; }

    public Harvest_Client selectedClientid { get; set; }

    private string client { get { return ClientText.Text; } set { ClientText.Text=value;} }
    private string application { get { return ApplicationText.Text; } set { ApplicationText.Text = value; } }
    private string starttime { get { return StartTimeText.Text; } set { StartTimeText.Text = value; } }
    private string stoptime { get { return StopTimeText.Text; } set { StopTimeText.Text = value; } }
    private string task { get { return TaskText.Text; } set { TaskText.Text = value; } }
    private string project { get { return ProjectText.Text; } set { ProjectText.Text = value; } }

    public CustomView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        Globals._globalController.setCustomViewWindow(this);

        clientList = Globals._globalController.harvestManager._CLIENTLIST;
        projectList = Globals._globalController.harvestManager._PROJECTLIST;

    }

    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (sender is Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)
        {

            //Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entry = new Harvest_TimeSheetEntry();

            //if (!entry.isSynced)
            //{
            //    entry.ClientNameBinding = client;
            //    entry.ApplicationNameBinding = application;
            //    entry.StartTimeBinding = starttime;
            //    entry.StopTimeBinding = stoptime;
            //    entry.TaskNameBinding = task;
            //    entry.ProjectNameBinding = project;
            //}

            Globals._globalController.getDayViewWindow.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
   }

    private void ClientComboBoxChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    private void ProjectComboBoxChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

}
}
```

I don't understand, how should i save this data in DayView listbox. Please suggest some ways.!

This is DayView window

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qi0e.png
```

This is CustomView window!

```
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mACxR.png
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's more suitable to use an mvvm Framework to make your solution more structured, and then use a Messenger to make communication between your views.